# Passing data between React-Native js and Obj-C Bridge

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I've simplified my call to pass a simple string from react-native index.ios.js to Obj-C native module, and I still get an error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

My code is as follows:

js (called by a TouchableOpacity component):

```
ring() {
    Twilio.connect('+447842111281');
}
```

Obj-C:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(connect:(NSString *)number) {
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"To": number};
    _connection = [_phone connect:params delegate:nil];
}
```

If anyone has any insights that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use convert macro:

```
NSString *numberString = [RCTConvert NSString:number]
```